# UrlReferrer shows a value with hyperlink but null with Response.Redirect

Tags: asp.net, http, hyperlink, httprequest, response.redirect

I am redirecting between two pages, when I use a `hyperlink` I get the Page1 in the `UrlReferrer` field, but using `Response.Redirect` gives it null.

AFAIK both of them act similarly for a redirection. Can anyone help me understand this behaviour?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try another computer?
or maybe just a new blank solution?

for me it works great.

Comment: ^^ Yeah, thats the problem. Its working fine on a fresh new solution, its just that within my client application it is behaving the same way even on a different machine..